# Splitting the string except for symbols

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

I tried using these 2 codes:

```
Dim splitQuery() As String = Regex.Split(TextBoxQuery.Text, "\s+")
```

and

```
Dim splitQuery() As String = TextBoxQuery.Text.Split(New Char() {" "c})
```

My example query is `a dog .` Notice there's a single space between `dog` and `.`. When I check the length of splitQuery, it gives me 3 and the split words are `a`, `dog`, and `.`.

How can I stop it from counting `.` and other symbols as word? I want words/terms (alphanumeric) only to be stored in my splitQuery array. Thanks.

Comment: Do you intend to trim the string from the non-word chars at the end? Just use `Regex.Replace(str, "\W*$", "", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)` and then split with `\s+`.

Comment: Does [this code](http://ideone.com/2Zh5J1) work for you?

Comment: this the most efficient answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest doing that in 2 steps:

- Use `txt = Regex.Replace(TextBoxQuery.Text, "\W+$", "", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)` to remove the non-word characters from the end of the string
- Then, split with `\s+`: `splits = Regex.Split(txt, "\s+")`

If you prefer to split with any non-word chars, you may use

```
splits = Regex.Split(Regex.Replace(TextBoxQuery.Text, "^\W+|\W+$", ""), "\W+")
```

Here, `Regex.Replace(TextBoxQuery.Text, "^\W+|\W+$", "")` removes non-word chars both at the start and end of string.

Answer (score 0):

you should also be able to create a string of unwanted characters and trim them with a stringsplitoption to RemoveEmptyEntries.

```
dim unwanted as string = "./?!#"
Dim splitQuery() as string = yourString.Trim(unwanted.tochararray).Split(New Char() {" "c}), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: I guess it would take time listing all the unwanted characters esp. all the symbols and I may forget some. I still thank you for your answer. I may apply it on other cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this problem in two parts.

1. I would split up the text by spaces like you're doing
2. I would then run through that list of words and remove any query terms that are non-alphanumeric.

The following is an example of that:

```
Imports System.Collections

' ... Your Other Code ...

    ' A function to determine if a string is AlphaNumeric
    Private Function IsAlphaNum(ByVal strInputText As String) As Boolean
        Dim IsAlpha As Boolean = False
        If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(strInputText, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$") Then
            IsAlpha = True
        Else
            IsAlpha = False
        End If

        Return IsAlpha
    End Function

    ' A function to get the words from the textbox
    Private Function GetWords() As String()
        ' Get a raw list of all words separated by spaces
        Dim splitQuery() As String = Regex.Split(TextBoxQuery.Text, "\s+")

        ' ArrayList to place all words into:
        Dim alWords As New ArrayList()

        ' Loop all words and check them:
        For Each word As String In splitQuery
            If(IsAlphaNum(word)) Then
                ' Word is alphanumeric
                ' Add it to the list of alphanumeric words
                alWords.add(word)
            End If
        Next

        ' Convert the ArrayList of words to a primitive array of strings
        Dim words As String() = CType(alWords.ToArray(GetType(String)), String())

        ' Return the list of filtered words
        return words
    End Function
```

This code does the following:

1. splits up the textbox's text
2. declares an `ArrayList` for the filtered query terms/words
3. loops through all the words in the split up array of terms/words
4. it then checks if the term is alphanumeric
5. If the term is alphanumeric, it is added to the `ArrayList`. If it's not alphanumeric, the term is disregarded.
6. Finally, it casts the terms/words in the `ArrayList` back to a normal String array and returns.

Because this solution uses an `ArrayList`, it requires `System.Collections` as an import.

Comment: @stribizhev 's answer is shorter, I guess. Still, thank you for giving me another idea!